# How do I cluster my PRIMARY KEY in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I noticed in postgres when we create a table, it seems to automatically creates a btree index on the PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT. Looking at the properties of the CONSTRAINT, it would appear it is not clustered. How do I cluster it and should I cluster it?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `CLUSTER` command:

```
CLUSTER stone.unitloaddetail USING pk10;
```

Remember that this rewrites the table and blocks it for others during that time.

Also, clustering is not maintained when table data are modified, so you have to schedule regular `CLUSTER` runs if you want to keep the table clustered.

Comment: Is there a way to do this from pgadmin?

Comment: Probably. If all fails, you can open an SQL window and enter the command.

Comment: Just a thought, would it make more sense to use an index vs the primary key if i have to keep reclustering?

Comment: @DanielL.VanDenBosch: what do you mean with "index vs. primary key"? A primary key is enforced through a unique index. You can't have a PK without an index

Comment: Would it make more sense to use the clustered index on the pkey existing index or create a new index with reference to the pkey column and cluster that?

Comment: You should use the existing index. Additional indexes cost performance and disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the "should you" part, it depends on the likelihood of queries needing to access multiple rows having adjacent values of the clustering key.

For a table with a synthetic primary key, it probably makes more sense to cluster on a foreign key column.

Imagine that you have a table or products. Are you more likely to request multiple products having:

1. consecutive product_id?
2. the same location_id?
3. the same type_id?
4. the same manufacturer_id?

If it would solve a problem for you to improve the performance of the system for one of these particular cases, then that is the column by which you should consider clustering.

If doing so would not solve a problem, then do not do it.

Comment: frequently, at least in my example above. the primary key almost always is  arbitrary. However they are very often used in `JOIN`s. from what I have gathered. it seems like it would be a good idea to do the code provided by Laurenz Albe to CLUSTER the primary keys. Let me know your thoughts

Comment: @DanielL.VanDenBosch Yes, if you had a situation where you generate 20 invoice_lines for an invoice in one batch, then you'd expect the primary keys on the invoice_line to be sequential for a single invoice. However, the FK to the invoice table would be guaranteed to be the same for those lines, and clustering on that value would not only improve performance but would also better demonstrate your intent to future maintainers of the system. If this kind of association of PK values does not occur, do not cluster on it.